# if conditions are not working

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="layout">
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td id="t1" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                    <td id="t2" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                    <td id="t3" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="t4" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                    <td id="t5" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                    <td id="t6" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="t7" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                    <td id="t8" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                    <td id="t9" onclick="over(this)"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p id="a"></p>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                 var turn=0;
                function over(x) {

                    if (turn==0) {
                        x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                        turn=1;
                    }
                    if (turn==1) {
                        x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
                        turn=0;
                    }

                }

        </script>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

if statements are not working. it is showing only one image. Only 2nd if condition with turn==1 is working. i am trying to insert images alternatively.
Turn value is not changing. In every box it is inserting only o.png.
In starting `turn =0` but `if(turn==1)` condition is being executed always.

Comment: Hmmm, obviously a bug in the IF keyword. Contact Brendan.

Comment: change your function to:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an [`else if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) instead of a second `if`:

```
if (turn==0) {
    x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
    turn=1;
}
else if (turn==1) {
    x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
    turn=0;
}
```

Right now both both `if` statements are executed because the first `if` statement sets `turn` to `1`, and the second statement now sees that `turn` is equal to one, and thus "fires" as well setting `turn` back to zero and sets the image to `o.png`.

If there are only two players playing the game, which seems to be the case here, you can drop the second `if` statement and write:

```
if (turn==0) {
    x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
    turn=1;
}
else {
    x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
    turn=0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are changing the turn value and then checking it in the next if, so both ifs are executed in case of `turn = 0`, the first one and the second one:

```
                    if (turn==0) {
                        x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                        turn=1;
                    }
                    if (turn==1) {
                        x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
                        turn=0;
                    }
```

I assume you wanted `else if`, this way only one if will be executed always:

```
                    if (turn==0) {
                        x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                        turn=1;
                    }
                    else if (turn==1) {
                        x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
                        turn=0;
                    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is, that both statements are being executed, because the program enters the first conditional, sets `turn=1`,  and then evaluates the second statement, which is now true!

You should write

```
if (turn === 0) {
    x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
    turn = 1;
} else {
    x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
    turn = 0;
}
```

As an aside, if `turn` only alternates between `1` and `0` you should probably change it to be of type boolean:

```
even = true;    

function over(x) {    
    if (even) {        
       x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
    } else {
       x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
    }
    even = !even;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is wrongly placed. You are changing the value of the variable and then again checking the condition.

So your solution wil be,

```
if (turn == 0) {
    x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
    turn=1;
}
else if(turn == 1){
    x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
    turn=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code snippet, you are first setting the **initial value** of turn to be **equal to 0:** 
var turn=0;

Now, in the given code :

```
                if (turn==0) {
                    x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                    turn=1;
                }
                if (turn==1) {
                    x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
                    turn=0;
                }

            }
```

the first 'if condition' evaluates to true, because, turn is indeed equal to 0. Hence, the HTML DOM's content is being set to the 'x.png' image and the value of 'turn' variable is being **flipped** to 1. 
In this very case, you **don't** want to **execute the second 'if'** statement, hence it must be **replaced by 'else if'**, so that only one of the two gets evaluated.

The **correct code** should hence be:

```
            if (turn==0) {
                x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                turn=1;
            }
            else if (turn==1) {
                x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
                turn=0;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply end the exectution of each using the return function.

```
            var turn=0;
            function over(x) {

                if (turn==0) {
                    x.innerHTML="<img src='x.png'/>";
                    turn=1;return;
                }
                if (turn==1) {
                    x.innerHTML="<img src='o.png'/>";
                    turn=0;return;
                }

            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Conditions are not placed correctly. use if{...} else if{...}, if you want to execute the same code inside the conditions.